# 複数行のテキスト：positionで場所固定すると、全行にあった下線が消えてしまう

Tags: html, css

2行以上あるテキスト文に対して、全行に下線をつけたいです。
下記コードでつけることはできました。

```css
    .test{
        display: inline;
        background:linear-gradient(transparent 60%, #f940bc 0%);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="test">1行目です<br>こんにちは2行目です</div>
```

htmlは同じで、下記のようにpositionで位置を固定すると、1行目にあった下線が消えてしまいます。

```
.test{
    display: inline;
    background:linear-gradient(transparent 60%, #f940bc 0%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10rem;
    left: 5rem;
}
```

1行目と2行目をdivで分けて、それぞれに下線を指定すれば1行目にも適応はされますが、このhtmlのコードのまま出来ないか、またpositionで固定すると何故1行目の下線が消えてしまうのか疑問でした。よろしくお願い致します。

**positionを指定してない時:**

[image: positionを指定してない時]

**positio:absoluteで固定した場合:**

[image: positio:absoluteで固定した場合]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background: linear-gradient(...` ですから、文字に下線が付いているのではなくて、CSS box の下の方に背景画像としてグラデーションが描かれています。`display: inline` の場合は改行が入ると CSS box が複数に別れて、それぞれの CSS box に背景画像が描画されます。

`position: absolute` を付けると、**`display: inline` は無効になってブロック扱い**になります。
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#position-property

> A position value of absolute or fixed blockifies the box,

ブロックは1つの CSS box ですから、背景画像も1つしか描画されません。

解決策としてはHTMLを変更するか、CSS で(グラデーションではなく)下線を引くといいかもしれません。

```css
.test {
    text-decoration: underline 40% #f940bc;
    text-underline-offset: -0.3em;
    text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">1行目です<br>こんにちは2行目です</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

position: absolute;で絶対参照になっていて、top: 10rem;で位置指定しているからじゃないですか。

Answer (score 1):

`position: absolute` を指定すると、 `display` には `inline` を指定していても `block` として計算されます。

#### 仕様

最新ではないかも知れませんが、下記の仕様が該当すると思います。（追記: [int32_tさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/95688/3054)にある仕様の方が新しいと思いますので、そちらを参照した方が良いかも知れません）

- 原文: [『9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'』](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)
- 翻訳: [『9.7 'display'、'position'、'float'の関係』](https://momdo.github.io/css2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

抜粋:

> ...
> `position` が値 `absolute` または `fixed` を持つ場合、ボックスは絶対位置であり、'float'の算出値は'none'となり、かつ表示は下記のテーブルに従って設定される。
> ...
>
> | 指定値 | 算出値 |
> | --- | --- |
> | inline-table | table |
> | inline、table-row-group、table-column、table-column-group、table-header-group、table-footer-group、table-row、table-cell、table-caption、inline-block | block |
> | その他 | 指定値と同じ |

#### 対処

HTMLの構造を変えずにこれに対処する方法は思い付きません。何らかの、`position: absolute` の要素で、目的の文章部分の要素を包むのが良いと思います。

```css
.underline {
  display: inline;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 60%, #f940bc 0%);
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class=underline>1行目です<br>こんにちは2行目です</span>
</div>
```